# Combine consecutive numbers into range tuples

Tags: python, algorithm, list

I have a list like

```
[38, 98, 110, 111, 112, 120, 121, 898]
```

How can I merge consecutive numbers into a pair representing a range?

desired output:

```
['38',
 '98', 
 '110,112',
 '120,121',
 '898']
```

Comment: why is 110->112 considered consecutive?

Comment: @hexparrot he has 110, 111, 112; I think he means to include all numbers in the 'range' until he reaches a number which is no longer consecutive.

Comment: ah, such a silly oversight. now, i recall a codegolf that does this...brb.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can do this nicely with itertools.groupby by noticing that the difference between the items in your list, and a counter are constant while the numbers are consecutive

eg

```
38 - 0 = 38
98 - 1 = 97
110 - 2 = 108
111 - 3 = 108
112 - 4 = 108
120 - 5 = 115
121 - 6 = 115
898 - 7 = 891
```

in this example, the 108's are grouped together and the 115's are grouped together. Now some code

```
>>> from itertools import groupby, count
>>> L = [38, 98, 110, 111, 112, 120, 121, 898]
>>> groups = groupby(L, key=lambda item, c=count():item-next(c))
>>> tmp = [list(g) for k, g in groups]
```

see what we have so far

```
>>> tmp
[[38], [98], [110, 111, 112], [120, 121], [898]]
```

convert to the desired result

```
>>> [str(x[0]) if len(x) == 1 else "{},{}".format(x[0],x[-1]) for x in tmp]
['38', '98', '110,112', '120,121', '898']
```

Answer (score 4):

A straight-forward solution:

```
def ranger(lst):
    fr, to = lst[0], lst[0]
    for x in lst[1:]:
        if x == to+1:
            to = x
        else:
            yield fr, to
            fr, to = x, x
    yield fr, to

res = [','.join(map(str, sorted(set(x)))) for x in ranger(lst)]
```

Comment: the output doesnt match it makes a duplicate of the single numbers and pairs them